# How to get time zone as a String in C# ?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I need to get time zone of PC as below format.

> (UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta

How can I get it as a string ?

Answer (score 21):

Just use the `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName` property:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.Local; // For example
Console.WriteLine(zone.DisplayName);
```

Or for your precise example:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SE Asia Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine(zone.DisplayName); // (UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta
```

Comment: Even I change the time zone of my PC. It will print 

(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta. I want to change it according to PC time Zone

Comment: @Sachith: If your program is already running when you manually change the time zone, you'll need to call `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`. That's not really part of what you asked though, so I won't be adding it into the answer.

Answer (score -3):

I have used below code to get the datetime from different zones.

```
  TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo;

        DateTime dateTime;

        //Set the time zone information to Australia Standard Time 

        timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Cen. Australia Standard Time");

        //Get date and time in Australia Standard Time 

        dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);

        //Print out the date and time

        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Refer this below link for More info about time zone names:
http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-_net-convert-datetime-from-one-timezone-to-another-7e44y.aspx

Comment: Not an answer to what was asked.